# How to scrape stopped Docker containers?

Tags: docker, prometheus, alert, grafana-agent

I use [Grafana Agent](https://grafana.com/docs/agent/latest/) to scrape all my Docker containers.  Therefore, I use Prometheus' [`<docker_sd_config>`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#docker_sd_config). It works for running Docker containers, but not for stopped Docker containers. No alerts are sent.

**Configuration**

```yaml
  configs:
    - name: agent
      scrape_configs:

      - job_name: docker
        metrics_path: '/prometheus'
        docker_sd_configs:
          - host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
        relabel_configs:
          - source_labels: [__meta_docker_port_private]
            regex: '8081'
            action: keep
          - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_name']
            regex: '/(.*)'
            target_label: 'job'
```

**Alert rule**

```yaml
- alert: ServerDown
    expr: up{} < 1
    for: 15m
    annotations:
      summary: Server down
```

**Docker containers**

```
f8070378f38b   gitlab.mycomp.com:5005/test/my-app1:latest    "java -jar app.jar"      2 weeks ago     Up 12 hours (healthy)        0.0.0.0:8205->8081/tcp, :::8205->8081/tcp                                                                                                                 my-app1
c4a5042b9fcf   gitlab.mycomp.com:5005/test/my-app2:latest    "java -jar app.jar"      2 weeks ago     Exited (143) 40 seconds ago                                                                                                                                                             my-app2
```

**Research**

- If I use [`<static_config>`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#static_config) it works, but I don't want to list all my Docker containers manually. I want to use the service discovery.

**Question**

How to scrape stopped Docker containers with Grafana Agent?

Comment: How do you expect to scrape from a container that's not running? That's like asking how to log on to a PC that's shut down.

Comment: @SiHa That is not a problem, Prometheus tries to scrape, fails and knows that the service is down. That works perfectly if I use [static_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#static_config). Do you know Prometheus? That is a regular use case for all productive environments.

Comment: Yes, I use Prometheus daily. I think perhaps, I misunderstood the problem. It reads like you're trying to scrape metrics from the stopped containers, but you're actually just trying to list all containers, including stopped ones?

Comment: @SiHa Sure, the docker service discovery lists all containers and then Prometheus scrape every container on the list. If the scraping fails, Prometheus knows that the container is not up and an alert is created and later send with the altermanager.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there seem to be no easy switch to enable that. The API used to retrieve the list of containers (https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#tag/Container) has the option to show all but I don't see an option to use it in `docker_sd_configs`. However, there is an option to specify `filters`. I'm not sure if it would work, but maybe if you can create such a filter, that'll cover all containers. Something like this:

```yaml
docker_sd_configs:
- host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  # Optional filters to limit the discovery process to a subset of available
  # resources.
  # The available filters are listed in the upstream documentation:
  # https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerList
  filters:
  # Not sure which is correct, try either this:
  - name: status
    values: created, restarting, running, removing, paused, exited, dead
  # or this:
  - name: status
    values: created
  - name: status
    values: restarting
  - name: status
    values: running
  - name: status
    values: removing
  - name: status
    values: paused
  - name: status
    values: exited
  - name: status
    value: dead
```